# Leap Motion Coordinate system re targeting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm trying to change the leap motion default coordinate system from the Leap Motion Controller to A Bone in a skeleton.

This script comes with the leap and I was hoping someone might help me with how I can achieve this.

```
/******************************************************************************\
* Copyright (C) Leap Motion, Inc. 2011-2014.                                   *
* Leap Motion proprietary. Licensed under Apache 2.0                           *
* Available at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html                 *
\******************************************************************************/

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Leap;

// Interface for all hands.
public abstract class HandModel : MonoBehaviour {
  public const int NUM_FINGERS = 5;
  public float handModelPalmWidth = 0.085f;
  public FingerModel[] fingers = new FingerModel[NUM_FINGERS];

  protected Hand hand_;
  protected HandController controller_;
  protected bool mirror_z_axis_ = false;

  public Vector3 GetHandOffset() {
    if (controller_ == null || hand_ == null)
      return Vector3.zero;

    Vector3 additional_movement = controller_.handMovementScale - Vector3.one;
    Vector3 scaled_wrist_position =
        Vector3.Scale(additional_movement, hand_.WristPosition.ToUnityScaled(mirror_z_axis_));

    return controller_.transform.TransformPoint(scaled_wrist_position) -
           controller_.transform.position;
  }

  // Returns the palm position of the hand in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetPalmPosition() {
    return controller_.transform.TransformPoint(hand_.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled(mirror_z_axis_)) +
           GetHandOffset();
  }

  // Returns the palm rotation of the hand in relation to the controller.
  public Quaternion GetPalmRotation() {
    return GetController().transform.rotation * GetLeapHand().Basis.Rotation(mirror_z_axis_);
  }

  // Returns the palm direction of the hand in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetPalmDirection() {
    return controller_.transform.TransformDirection(hand_.Direction.ToUnity(mirror_z_axis_));
  }

  // Returns the palm normal of the hand in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetPalmNormal() {
    return controller_.transform.TransformDirection(hand_.PalmNormal.ToUnity(mirror_z_axis_));
  }

  // Returns the lower arm direction in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetArmDirection() {
    return controller_.transform.TransformDirection(hand_.Arm.Direction.ToUnity(mirror_z_axis_));
  }

  // Returns the lower arm center in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetArmCenter() {
    Vector leap_center = 0.5f * (hand_.Arm.WristPosition + hand_.Arm.ElbowPosition);
    return controller_.transform.TransformPoint(leap_center.ToUnityScaled(mirror_z_axis_)) +
           GetHandOffset();
  }

  // Returns the lower arm elbow position in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetElbowPosition() {
    Vector3 local_position = hand_.Arm.ElbowPosition.ToUnityScaled(mirror_z_axis_);
    return controller_.transform.TransformPoint(local_position) + GetHandOffset();
  }

  // Returns the lower arm wrist position in relation to the controller.
  public Vector3 GetWristPosition() {
    Vector3 local_position = hand_.Arm.WristPosition.ToUnityScaled(mirror_z_axis_);
    return controller_.transform.TransformPoint(local_position) + GetHandOffset();
  }

  // Returns the rotation quaternion of the arm in relation to the controller.
  public Quaternion GetArmRotation() {
    Quaternion local_rotation = hand_.Arm.Basis.Rotation(mirror_z_axis_);
    return controller_.transform.rotation * local_rotation;
  }

  public Hand GetLeapHand() {
    return hand_;
  }

  public void SetLeapHand(Hand hand) {
    hand_ = hand;
    for (int i = 0; i < fingers.Length; ++i) {
      if (fingers[i] != null) {
        fingers[i].SetLeapHand(hand_);
        fingers[i].SetOffset(GetHandOffset());
      }
    }
  }

  public void MirrorZAxis(bool mirror = true) {
    mirror_z_axis_ = mirror;
    for (int i = 0; i < fingers.Length; ++i) {
      if (fingers[i] != null)
        fingers[i].MirrorZAxis(mirror);
    }
  }

  public bool IsMirrored() {
    return mirror_z_axis_;
  }

  public HandController GetController() {
    return controller_;
  }

  public void SetController(HandController controller) {
    controller_ = controller;
    for (int i = 0; i < fingers.Length; ++i) {
      if (fingers[i] != null)
        fingers[i].SetController(controller_);
    }
  }

  public abstract void InitHand();

  public abstract void UpdateHand();
}
```

Having some issue with my syntax as I am a novice.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use Leapmotion for moving character hands?

Comment: Can you shoot me an email at acolgan@leapmotion.com? I'd be happy to put you in touch with one of our Unity engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can completely understand your question. But if you want to transform data into a skeleton then see this code.

```
 // using Mesh, a custom class of mine
public List<GeometryModel3D> drawLeftHand(Hand hand) {
        List<GeometryModel3D> list = new List<GeometryModel3D>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.Fingers.Count; i++)
        {
           // material = materials[i];
            Finger finger = hand.Fingers[i];
            List<Bone> allBones = new List<Bone>();

            Bone _m = finger.Bone(Leap.Bone.BoneType.TYPE_METACARPAL);
            Bone _pp = finger.Bone(Leap.Bone.BoneType.TYPE_PROXIMAL);
            Bone _ip = finger.Bone(Leap.Bone.BoneType.TYPE_INTERMEDIATE);
            Bone _dp = finger.Bone(Leap.Bone.BoneType.TYPE_DISTAL);
            allBones.Add(_m);
            allBones.Add(_pp);
            allBones.Add(_ip);
            allBones.Add(_dp);

            for (int j = 0; j < allBones.Count; j++)
            {
                material = materials[j];
                if (allBones[j].IsValid)
                {
                    Vector before = allBones[j].PrevJoint;

                    GeometryModel3D sphere = new GeometryModel3D(mesh.createSphere(new Point3D(before.x, before.y, before.z)), material);
                    list.Add(sphere);
                    Vector after = allBones[j].NextJoint;
                    GeometryModel3D cylinder = new GeometryModel3D(mesh.createCylinder(new Point3D(before.x, before.y, before.z), new Point3D(after.x, after.y, after.z)), material);
                            list.Add(cylinder);

                            if (j == allBones.Count - 1)
                            {
                                Vector last = allBones[j].NextJoint;
                                GeometryModel3D _sphere = new GeometryModel3D(mesh.createSphere(new Point3D(last.x, last.y, last.z)), material);
                                list.Add(_sphere);
                            }       
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The point here is to get in order each pair of joints and connect them with a bone to have something like O-o-o-o

I can not share my whole project yet. I will GitHub it soon thou. But if you have any question feel free to ask.